# Yii - loading html file data in to drop down list using Jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, yii

Here is the plain HTML code which is working and want to move this to Yii framework .

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

          <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $.get("dist_list.html",
                    function(dist){
                    $("#sourceModels").html(dist);
                });
            });
        </script>
     </head>
    <body>
        <select id="sourceModels"  size="20" ></select>
    </body>
</html>
```

in the above code I am calling **dist_list.html** which is simple list

```
<option value='1'>AAA</option>
<option value='2'>BBB</option>
<option value='3'>CCC</option>
<option value='4'>DDD</option>
<option value='5'>EEE</option>
<option value='6'>FFF</option>
```

To Move this work to Yii framework , I moved java script code to a .js file and the **dist_list.html** copied to /components/js folder  ( Both .js and html in the same folder)

in view I am calling registering the script using

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(
    Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(
        Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.components').'/js/models.js'
    ),
    CClientScript::POS_END
);
```

which is working fine . I even checked this by putting some alert statements java script

and using the below drop down list code

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList("sourceModels", '',array(),array('class'=>'mandal','size'=>20) );?>
```

But the dropdown box is not getting the options from the html file which is getting called from Java script . I tried few paths changing when calling java script .

Could some one please help me on this ?

I am using the HTML just to load the options ( These options are fixed and even if there are changes max one ..two times) instead of database to save database calls . 
Any best approach you can suggest ? ( Don't want to copy them in the model ...)

Thank You

Regards

Kiran

Comment: seems like you are defeating the MVC structure of Yii so if you don't want to put the drop-down data in a model, you might as well simply fetch it with a php `include()` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList("sourceModels", '',array(),array('class'=>'mandal','size'=>20,'id'=>'sorceModels') );?>
```

it seems like you doesn't specify the dropdown id,so the js can't find the Dom correct.

Comment: Thanks for your response . That was problem and I corrected it . But still it is not finding the .html file

Comment: Ya it is looking for that file under /final/dist_list.html  . Since I copied it to components/js it is not finding it .

Comment: Actually I believe the "sourceModels" id should get created with the CHtml::dropDownList function as by default the ID is the same as the name attribute.

Comment: @idg :- Thank You , but it is not getting created . explicitly we have to mention it in other attributes